# Can we find real values of $x$ such that $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}c^n\prod\limits_{k= 1}^n| a_k x-1|=0$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Let $\{a_n\}$ be a sequence such that the sequence of [Cesaro means](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ces%C3%A0ro_mean) is convergent i.e. $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n a_k$$ exists. Let $c>1$ be a given number and I am trying to find the range of $x\in \mathbb{R}$ (if one exists) such that $$\lim_{n\to \infty}c^n\prod_{k= 1}^n| a_k x-1|=0$$ where $|\cdot|$ denotes the absolute value function. Had $c$ been $1$, I found that the simple condition $\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\prod_{k=1}^n|a_k x-1|\right)^{1/n}<1$ is a sufficient condition for the desired answer and I found a range of $x$ for this to happen. But if I try to use the same method here for $c>1$, it does not seem to work and depends on the structure of the $\{a_n\}$ sequence which makes me doubtful about this condition. So my question is does there exist a sufficient condition that ensures real values of $x$ for which the desired result is obtained? Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.